# Delete All Cells if not A-Z

Tags: vba, excel, ascii

I am working through 6 columns of data (A-F) rows 2-4379 and a large number of the cells appear as "Blanks" in the filter column but are not *true* blanks as they seem to contain spaces in them.  I was hoping to find some vba examples for finding all cells within a range that contained ASCII values between 65-90 and 97-122 and if those values were not contained within a cell, then to clear it completely.

Is this possible?  I have tried a sub that checked for "IsText" but kept getting a "sub or function not defined" error message relating to the IsText line.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:F4379")

For Each c in rng

If Not IsText(c.Value) Then
c.ClearContents
End If

Next c
```

Comment: is it just spaces you're trying to get rid of?  or are there other hidden characters.  Rather than loop through each cell, I think doing a find and replace on the range would be much, much faster.

Comment: Expanding on sous message, if you can find out what the 'space' character is (there are different ones it can be) then you can replace that particular character with vbnullstring - which is proper nothing.

You can find out by using =code(the character in question)

Comment: Or perhaps you could sort the range, the blank character should end up at the top or bottom of the sort

Comment: Also, I think you need to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(c.Value)` to access `istext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should remove most spaces from the active sheet:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub trimWhiteSpaces()

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        .Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:="  ", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:="   ", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:="    ", Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole

        .Replace What:=vbTab, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbCrLf, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbCr, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbLf, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbNewLine, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole

        .Replace What:=vbNullChar, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbBack, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbFormFeed, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbVerticalTab, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole
        .Replace What:=vbObjectError, Replacement:=vbNullString, LookAt:=xlWhole

    End With

End Sub
```

.

As a note:

Your initial code had the error because you didn't include it in a Sub()

You can fix it by using a structure similar to this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub testSub()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("A2:F4379")

    For Each c In rng
        If Not IsText(c.Value) Then
            c.ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Within a sub it doesn't work because you need `application.worksheetfunction.istext()`

Comment: You are awesome! Worked perfectly!